# PDF Rendering in Canvas PDF JS

Tags: javascript, pdf.js

I am trying to render pages in a pdf one by one upon scroll as they have in the demo of PDF JS. I am using PDF JS. i have rendered all the pages at once, but that is taking some time to load all the pages. 
So basically the idea is to load the pdf faster as in the demo of PDF Js.

I have shared the code below where i have rendered all the pages at once but that is taking a little more time than expected.

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PDF JS Demo</title>
        <style>
            #holder {
                width: 100%;
                height: 500px;
                overflow: auto;
                background: #333;
                text-align: center;
                border: 1px solid;
                margin-bottom: 25px;
            }
            canvas {
                margin-bottom: 15px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
<body>

<script src="build/pdf.js"></script>
<script src="build/pdf.worker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="build/simple.js"></script>

<div id="holder"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
reUsableRenderPDF('build/HygieneReport_New.pdf', document.getElementById('holder'));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function reUsableRenderPDF(url, canvasContainer, options) {

    var options = options || { zoom: 1.0 };

    function renderPage(page) {
        var viewport = page.getViewport(options.zoom);
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var renderContext = {
          canvasContext: ctx,
          viewport: viewport
        };

        canvas.height = viewport.height;
        canvas.width = viewport.width;

        canvasContainer.appendChild(canvas);

        page.render(renderContext);
    }

    function renderPages(pdfDoc) {
        for(var num = 1; num <= pdfDoc.numPages; num++)
            pdfDoc.getPage(num).then(renderPage);
    }

    pdfjsLib.disableWorker = true;
    pdfjsLib.getDocument(url).then(renderPages);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should render only a number of pages of pdf, not all pages of pdf at once, So that's say you are at page number 5 you can render pages 3 4 and 6 7 but to do this you need to know current location of page that you are and to get pages that are near to the current page number and to render them as well but when you scroll to different page you need to remove older renders from HTML.

Answer (score 0):

you didn't really ask a specific question. But as to why the pdf may be rendering slowly it could be the size of the pdf, there being a lot of content within the pdf or a number of other things.
You could also try the cdn instead of including the build files:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdfjs-dist@2.1.266/build/pdf.min.js"></script>
```